# Virtual directory in JBoss AS 7.1.1 and Grails 2.3.8

Tags: grails, groovy, jboss

I am trying to render images from a folder that resides outside of the war file. I had to do this in order to prevent the images from being deleted when a new war file is deployed.

On my development machine, I was able to accomplish this by using _Event.groovy file with following contents.

```
import org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader

eventConfigureTomcat = { tomcat ->
def newContextRoot = "img"
File newContextPath = new File( "c:/temp/img" )

if( newContextPath.exists() ) {
    context = tomcat.addWebapp( newContextRoot, newContextPath.getAbsolutePath() )
    context.reloadable = true
    WebappLoader loader = new WebappLoader( tomcat.class.classLoader )
    context.loader = loader
}
}
```

With this I can access the images easily from my Grails app. However, when I deploy the app as a war file in a JBoss instance, the virtual directory doesn't work.

I have added this context file in META-INF folder but it is still now working.

```
<Context docBase='C:/temp/img' path='/img' />
```

I am running Grails 2.3.8 on JBoss AS 7.1.1

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated?

Comment: Have you tried without the `c:`? Windows specific stuff in paths is a bad thing